# Java 8 CompletedFuture web crawler doesn't crawl past one URL

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, java-8, web-crawler, completable-future

I'm playing with the newly introduced concurrency features in Java 8, working exercises from the book "Java SE 8 for the Really Impatient" by Cay S. Horstmann. I created the following web crawler using the new [CompletedFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) and [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/). The basic idea is given a URL, it'll find first *m* URLs on that page and repeat the process *n* times. *m* and *n* are parameters, of course. Problem is the program fetches the URLs for the initial page but doesn't recurse. What am I missing?

```
static class WebCrawler {
    CompletableFuture<Void> crawl(final String startingUrl,
        final int depth, final int breadth) {
        if (depth <= 0) {
            return completedFuture(startingUrl, depth);
        }

        final CompletableFuture<Void> allDoneFuture = allOf((CompletableFuture[]) of(
            startingUrl)
            .map(url -> supplyAsync(getContent(url)))
            .map(docFuture -> docFuture.thenApply(getURLs(breadth)))
            .map(urlsFuture -> urlsFuture.thenApply(doForEach(
                depth, breadth)))
            .toArray(size -> new CompletableFuture[size]));

        allDoneFuture.join();

        return allDoneFuture;
    }

    private CompletableFuture<Void> completedFuture(
        final String startingUrl, final int depth) {
        LOGGER.info("Link: {}, depth: {}.", startingUrl, depth);

        CompletableFuture<Void> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
        future.complete(null);

        return future;
    }

    private Supplier<Document> getContent(final String url) {
        return () -> {
            try {
                return connect(url).get();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new UncheckedIOException(
                    " Something went wrong trying to fetch the contents of the URL: "
                        + url, e);
            }
        };
    }

    private Function<Document, Set<String>> getURLs(final int limit) {
        return doc -> {
            LOGGER.info("Getting URLs for document: {}.", doc.baseUri());

            return doc.select("a[href]").stream()
                .map(link -> link.attr("abs:href")).limit(limit)
                .peek(LOGGER::info).collect(toSet());
        };
    }

    private Function<Set<String>, Stream<CompletableFuture<Void>>> doForEach(
          final int depth, final int breadth) {
        return urls -> urls.stream().map(
            url -> crawl(url, depth - 1, breadth));
    }
}
```

Test case:

```
@Test
public void testCrawl() {
    new WebCrawler().crawl(
        "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29",
        2, 10);
}
```

Comment: What are `allOf` and `of` in `allOf((CompletableFuture[]) of(startingUrl)`?

Comment: What is `Document`? Please post a reproducible example.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis This is working code; `allOf` and `of` are static imports; `Document` is a `jsoup` class. I don't want to clutter the post with bunch of imports. Here's the [code](https://github.com/abhijitsarkar/java/blob/master/java8-impatient/src/main/java/name/abhijitsarkar/java/java8impatient/concurrency/PracticeQuestionsCh6.java).

Comment: Seems to work fine for me. How are you calling `crawl`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis See edit, I added a test case.

Comment: Please also post the results you get and what you actually expected.

Comment: What I expect is clearly mentioned in my question. Here it is again: "Problem is the program fetches the URLs for the initial page but doesn't recurse.". Let me rephrase it: I'm only getting the URLs from the initial URL passed whereas the program is expected to recurse until it meets the depth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the following code:

```
final CompletableFuture<Void> allDoneFuture = allOf(
  (CompletableFuture[]) of(startingUrl)
    .map(url -> supplyAsync(getContent(url)))
    .map(docFuture -> docFuture.thenApply(getURLs(breadth)))
    .map(urlsFuture -> urlsFuture.thenApply(doForEach(depth, breadth)))
    .toArray(size -> new CompletableFuture[size]));
```

For some reason you are doing all this inside a stream of one element (is that a part of the exercise?).  The result is that `allDoneFuture` is not tracking the completion of the sub-tasks.  It's tracking the completion of the `Stream<CompletableFuture>` that comes from `doForEach`.  But that stream is ready right away and the futures inside of it are never asked to complete.

Fix it by removing the stream that doesn't do anything helpful:

```
final CompletableFuture<Void> allDoneFuture=supplyAsync(getContent(startingUrl))
    .thenApply(getURLs(breadth))
    .thenApply(doForEach(depth,breadth))
    .thenApply(futures -> futures.toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new))
    .thenCompose(CompletableFuture::allOf);
```

Comment: Thank you. I figured out the problem and had solved it in a slightly different manner. I'll accept your answer as it makes better sense. Unfortunately, code in comment is going to look ugly. `of(startingUrl).map(url -> supplyAsync(getContent(url))).map(docFuture -> docFuture.thenApply(getURLs(breadth))).map(urlsFuture -> urlsFuture.thenAccept(doForEach(depth, breadth))).findFirst()     .orElseThrow(completionException("Something went wrong when crawling URL: " + startingUrl)).join();`

Comment: A few more changes to support the above was also made which I'd have shown but not as a comment. BTW, in your answer, the `thenCompose` could be changed to a `thenAccept`, which I believe is more fitting. They work the same in this case.

Comment: I'm doing similar and I have trouble with running this with ExecutorService and multiple threads... If I put executor service in supplyAsync then it crawl only N pages (n = num of threads). Any idea?